# How to subset point data by outside of polygon data in R

Tags: r, point, point-in-polygon, subset

How can I subset point data from outside of polygon data in R?
Currently, I can subset point data inside polygon data,
now I want to get point data outside polygon data.

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc_point <- st_sample(x = nc, size = 100)
nc1 <- nc[1:50,]

nc_point[nc1]  %>% st_geometry() %>% plot(add=T,pch=16,col="blue")
```

I want to get the data easily as follows.

```
nc_point[!nc1]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can see which polygons are under points with:

```
st_intersects(nc_point, nc1)
```

which returns a list of the same length as `nc_point`. If the point isn't in a polygon then it returns `integer(0)` elements.

So you can any of a few ways of turning that output into TRUE/FALSE to then select your points. For example, look for length-0 elements in the list:

```
sapply(st_intersects(nc_point, nc1),function(x){length(x)==0})
```

That gives you a logical vector you can subset with:

```
> b = sapply(st_intersects(nc_point, nc1),function(x){length(x)==0})
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, it is assumed that they are planar
> nc_point[b]
Geometry set for 61 features 
geometry type:  POINT
```